# **NOVNC** password field is unknown

Tags: html, websocket, vnc

i have installed novnc server according to their instructions at https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC.Its all good.I get the URL too.When i run the URL on my browser,a pop up is diplayed with fields for host ,port and password.
host and port fields are filled with there respective values.I am confused about the password.I tried without password, it doesn't work.i had never set the password during the installation.Am i missing anything.Please guide me.

i get error code 1006
i am using ubuntu.
python 2.7

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Um, I'm not sure if you still read this topic, but yes, you were missing "something".
Have you actually set up your server? The noVNC does create a virtual server (not quite sure if this is the correct term).

But before using noVNC, you need to set up your own server like this:

```
X:~ # vncserver --help
TightVNC Server version 1.3.9

Usage: vncserver [<OPTIONS>] [:<DISPLAY#>]
```

I've tryed this with TightVNC for openSUSE. If I try to set up a server without a password, I've got this error:

```
X:~ # vncserver 

You will require a password to access your desktops.
```

Then you should be able to view your server via noVNC.